# How can I improve my testbench for testing a 1024x4 RAM memory in Verilog

Tags: verilog, ram, testbench

This is a question following on from my previous one "How can I improve my testbench for testing a 1024x4 RAM memory in Verilog".

Basically, I have modified the previous solution in an attempt to test a 1024x4 RAM memory, which uses coincident decoding and was implemented using gate-level description.

I have modified the code to use a for loop to run through the coincidental addresses of the decoders, for both the write and read operations.

My test bench works with regards to the write operation and as long as the read portion of the code  is commented out.

Please see code below:

```
module tb_RAM_1024x4();
wire  [3:0] Mem [0:1023];
wire  [3:0] DataOut;
reg   [3:0] DataIn;
reg   [4:0] X_Address,Y_Address;
reg   Enable, ReadWrite;   

RAM_1024x4    M0 (DataOut, DataIn, X_Address, Y_Address, Enable, ReadWrite);

  initial begin  
  Enable = 0; 
  DataIn = 4'b0000;

  #10 ReadWrite = 0;

  end 

  // Write random data to specific addresses
  initial #28830 $finish;
  integer  i, j;
  initial begin  
     for(i = 0; i < 32; i = i + 1) begin
        #5 X_Address = i;
        for(j = 0; j < 32; j = j + 1) begin
           #5 Y_Address = j;
           write(X_Address, Y_Address, $random);
        end  
     end                
  end
  
//      initial begin  
//      Enable = 0; 
  
//      #20 ReadWrite = 1;

//      end 

    // Read data from specific addresses
//      initial #28830 $finish;
//      initial begin  
//         for(i = 0; i < 32; i = i + 1) begin
//           #5 X_Address = i;
//           for(j = 0; j < 32; j = j + 1) begin
//              #5 Y_Address = j;
//              read(X_Address, Y_Address);
//           end
//         end
//      end
  

 task write (input [4:0] addr1, [4:0] addr2,[3:0] din);
    begin
       #20 X_Address = addr1; Y_Address = addr2; 
       #1 Enable = 0; 
       #2 Enable = 1; 
       DataIn = din;
    end
 endtask

 task read (input [4:0] addr1, [4:0] addr2);//, [3:0] dexpect);
    begin
       #20 X_Address = addr1; Y_Address = addr2; 
       #1 Enable = 0; 
       #2 Enable = 1; 
     end
  endtask
endmodule
```

Also provided is the waveform for the write operation. When the read portion of the code is uncommented, it affects the operation of the write operation for some reason which i haven't quite figured out.

Therefore, any insight that anyone can provide will be very much appreciated.[image: 1024x4 RAM Waveform]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uncommenting your read code, your `ReadWrite` signal was 1 for all your read and write calls.

You could combine your loops to interleave the writes and reads, dynamically changing `ReadWrite`.

```
integer  i, j;

initial #28830 $finish;

initial begin  
    Enable = 0; 
    DataIn = 4'b0000;
    ReadWrite = 0;
    X_Address = 0;
    Y_Address = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < 32; i = i + 1) begin
        #5 X_Address = i;
        for(j = 0; j < 32; j = j + 1) begin
            #5 Y_Address = j;

            ReadWrite = 0;
            write(X_Address, Y_Address, $random);

            #10;
            ReadWrite = 1;
            read(X_Address, Y_Address);
        end  
    end                
end
```

You could simplify it by moving `ReadWrite` inside the tasks (like `Enable`).

Comment: Thanks for the insight. It has allowed me to arrive at the solution that I was looking for, which is to write and read data to and from the addresses sequentially. I have moved the Enable command and ReadWrite requests out of the task functions, which have been discarded with and this has reduced the simulation time by approx. 80%.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution for a testbench that tests the write and read operation to the addresses within a 1024x4 RAM memory sequentially would be the following:

```
module tb_RAM_1024x4();
  wire    [3:0] Mem [0:1023];
  wire    [3:0] DataOut;
  reg     [3:0] DataIn;
  reg     [4:0] X_Address,Y_Address;
  reg     Enable, ReadWrite;   

  RAM_1024x4    M0 (DataOut, DataIn, X_Address, Y_Address, Enable, ReadWrite);

  // Write random data to specific addresses
  initial #11600 $finish;
  integer  i, j;
  initial begin  
     for(i = 0; i < 32; i = i + 1) begin
        #5 X_Address = i;
        Enable = 0; 
        for(j = 0; j < 32; j = j + 1) begin
           #5 Y_Address = j;  
           #1 DataIn = $random;
           Enable = 1; ReadWrite = 0;
        end  
     end 
     // Read data from specific addresses  
     for(i = 0; i < 32; i = i + 1) begin
        #5 X_Address = i;
        Enable = 0;
        for(j = 0; j < 32; j = j + 1) begin
           #5 Y_Address = j;
           Enable = 1; ReadWrite = 1;
        end
     end             
  end
endmodule
```

[image: 1024x4 RAM Memory Waveform]